# Disable Enter key on a Page created on sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I want to disable the  enter key on a particular page created on sharepoint 2010 site. The reason behind this is ...on this page I have deployed a single web part with many server controls, textbox, dropdowns etc. Whenever I click on these server controls or anywhere on the page , it enables the submit button.

Is there any way to achieve this, I tried to disable teh enter key on all teh web controls it works, but if I click apart from these web controls it does not.

I have used the below function for specifix textboxes etc.

```
 textbox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return DisableEnterKey(event);");
   function DisableEnterKey(evt)
   {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
      if (charCode == 13)
      {
        return false;
      }  
     return true;
   }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's some quirky behavior to enter-key submissions having to do with which controls are on (or missing from) your page.

I think asp.net lets you explicitly set a 'default button' attribute in the form tag (and also panel tags).

```
<form id="form_1" runat="server" defaultbutton="my_button1">
```

or

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_1" runat="server" defaultbutton="my_button2">
```

So one idea might be to set the default_button to some invisible, do-nothing button.  (or maybe you'd make it set the focus to one of your other controls...)